# how to fetch the current user data in phpfox

Tags: javascript, jquery, phpfox

Topic: Fetch current user(some particular fields) data from the DB and display it on the Welcome Screen.

Explaination of UI : On the Registration Page, A dropdown would appear. As the user selects an option, it would trigger an event to fetch user image to show on the welcome page.

I have put following code in (pages.process) module

```
  function getUserId($iUserId)
        {
        $aRows = $this->database()->select('p.image_path')->from($this->_sTable, 'p')
->Join(Phpfox::getT('user') , 'u', ' p.page_id = u.college_name') -> 
        where('u.college_name = p.page_id AND u.user_id = ' . 
    (int)$iUserId)->execute('getRows');
            return $aRows;
            }
```

The data will selected from User & Pages Table, and will be used to show the user image. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

There is a service to get user details by is

```
$user_id = Phpfox::getUserId();
$aRow  = Phpfox::getService('user')->getUser($user_id);
```

This will give you user details

Answer (score 0):

For performance, check if the page you are altering already has the information you need, maybe you dont need to query the database in ajax if the page, when being created, already has that info and you can store it in javascript.

Since you mentioned an ajax situation (trigger an event on drop down to query the database), then you need to include a JS file (my suggestion since you can do this from a plugin), there are other ways but this is the best in my opinion. 
Please read [my article](http://www.phpfox.com/kb/article/264/primer-on-hooks-plugins/) about plugins if you need help with writing one. My suggestion is to write a plugin to include your JS file in the page.

In the JS file you can call a "controller function" like this:

```
$.ajaxCall('mymodule.myfunction', 'param1=value1&param2=value2');
```

this would run the function "myfunction" in the file /module/mymodule/include/component/ajax/ajax.class.php
From this ajax file you can call "service functions" and send code to the browser, for example:

```
$value = Phpfox::getService('mmodule')->someOtherFunction();
$this->call('alert("' . $value . '");');
```

Hope it helps