# How do I get the current user details for a phpFox website?

Tags: php, phpfox

I am creating a webcam system to go on my phpFox site and am attempting to get the current user's ID. I've tried the following, but to no avail.

```
ob_start();
session_start();

function get_user_id() {
    $userid = null;
    $id = Phpfox::getUserBy('user_id');
    if (!empty($id)) {
        $userid = $id;
    }
    return $userid;
}

$idd = get_user_id();

echo("User ID: " . $idd);
```

How would I get the user ID of the current user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877907/how-to-fetch-the-current-user-data-in-phpfox Check it out it should help

Comment: Thanks but that did not help

Comment: Not even this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23495180/2310830

Comment: no it always gives a blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On module, you can use:

```
$iUserId = Phpfox::getUserId();
```

On App, you can use:

```
$iUserId = user()->id;
```

Answer (score 2):

In phpFox, you can get the current user ID with the following function:

```
$iUserId = Phpfox::getUserId();
```

Comment: do i need to `require();` or `include();` anything? my code is not a addon it is just a simple script just to the webcam module can know what user is starting the webcam

Comment: no you don't need to require anything this is default phpfox function